# Error using back arrow in toolbar within 3rd class level

Tags: android, android-toolbar

After clicking an item in a listview and going to the detail class, I click another button that takes me to another class. From within that class, if I click the back arrow it doesn't go back to the previous class.

**Log file**

```
Process: com.curtrostudios.testapp, PID: 8709
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.curtrostudios.testapp/com.curtrostudios.testapp.ProductDetail}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2356)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2418)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference
    at java.lang.StringToReal.parseFloat(StringToReal.java:304)
    at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:306)
    at java.lang.Float.valueOf(Float.java:343)
    at com.curtrostudios.testapp.ProductDetail.onCreate(ProductDetail.java:71)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2418) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

I have this in my Manifest:

```
    <application
        android:name=".VolleyController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ProductDetail"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.curtrostudios.testapp.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Comments"
            android:parentActivityName=".ProductDetail"
            >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.curtrostudios.testapp.ProductDetail" />
        </activity>
    </application>
```

The error happens when I try to go from the "Comments" class back to the "Detail" class even though the "Detail" class is defined as the parent activity for the "Comments" class while using the back arrow in the toolbar. Works fine if I just use the hardware back button.

Comment: post toolbar menu items listener code.

Comment: @bharat I don't have a toolbar declared in the "Comments" class. I just left the actionbar in the theme. It shows the back arrow though. When looking at the logcat, it says the error is caused by this line in the "Details" class when clicking the back arrow: `productRating.setRating(Float.valueOf(rating));` where "rating" is the intent string extra passed over from the main activity

Comment: post code of `ProductDetail` where crash happened..

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was. As I was trying to return to the parent activity, it was looking for the intent extra string for the float setting of the rating bar. To fix this, I had to continue passing the intent over to the next class and then back again. Might not be the clean way to do this but it works.